# Django file assertion

Tags: python, django, file, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I successfully `PATCH` my payload with `postman app`. In order to save up my time I wants to do it in code base not graphical base.

```py
    def test_owner_patch_avatar_and_background(self):
        client = APIClient()
        client.force_authenticate(user=self.jc)
        url = reverse('mobile_me')
        with open('media/background.jpg', 'rb') as background:
            with open('media/default.png', 'rb') as avatar:
                data = {
                    'avatar': avatar,
                    'background': background,
                }
                res = client.patch(url, data=data, format='multipart')
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.first()
        assert status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED == res.status_code
        assert background == user_profile.background
        assert avatar == user_profile.avatar
```

I stuck at in memory file assertion. I would like assert that saved files are the same as patched files. Currently I do assertion by `name` of them.
Here is debug line in my testcase.

```sh
In[4]: background
Out[4]: <_io.BufferedReader name='media/background.jpg'>
In[5]: user_profile.background
Out[5]: <ImageFieldFile: backgrounds/background_b4gQ4BS.jpg>
```

**Question:**
How do I assert between uploaded file and saved file in Python/Django REST?

Comment: You could call `.read()` on both files and compare the contents.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was totally forgot this!

Comment: @JohnGordon put your comment as question.